# time value of Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel-formula

In Excel , we Have TimeValue Function,for Example : TIMEVALUE("5:12:00 AM")     would return 0.216666667

Now, I have Entrytimes of Employees (7:10), I want to Save these Times into SQL Server as TimeValue value.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Cast(0.216666667 as dateTime)


Select Cast(Cast('5:12' as dateTime) as Float)
Select Cast(Cast('7:10' as dateTime) as Float)
```